# How to create Master Pages with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, master-pages

I have experience in traditional web development, but recently started using Wordpress. My company basically has 100 pages of the same page but with different city names/phone numbers for each page. Is there a way to create a master page that each of these pages could inherit from so that I can just make the unique changes of plugging in the city name/phone number on each page? This would vastly reduce the time it takes to make regular changes that need to be done on each page. I have tried googling it but I dont think templates will resolve my problem. I don't have much knowledge of php but am open to learning it if it will solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really an opinion question - since it's pretty open ended and there are many solutions. I would strongly look at creating a custom post type for this - however, that's my opinion. If your content is currently in a database, you could go a couple other routes, but again, this is too open ended.

Comment: Exactly you just need one Page template with design/markup. And this template will be used for all database entries with different data values to show on same design/pattern/template . Search google or this site for WP custom template, or Custom Post types and their templates.